# GitHub pages. Problem with domain

Tags: github-pages

I recently set up a small site with GitHub pages. I registered it on google search console and it was going well. I registered for a free domain ".tk" but that wasn't what I wanted so I cancelled it. Now when you search for my website you find the .tk domain(even though I cancelled it) and it doesn't bring you to my website.

How can I get the domain to point to my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.tk domains are very nasty, and often carry bad reputation for themselves. It would be better to ask your domain for cancellation to your host or  redirecting it somewhere else.

As for the github, you need to make clone your repo with the name 'gh-pages' and add a text file 'CNAME' with your domain name on it, github will set the rest itself. Though you need to configure the domain seeing at your domain provide.

Comment: While not prohibited, it's considered bad form to ask someone to accept your answer.  It's best to let the OP decide for themselves.

Answer (score -3):

To setup custom domain there is a one more option to add domain in the Github setting.